# iOS email encode with base 64

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64

Hello I want to send social login email address to my server. So I am encoding it with base64 in this way.

```
NSString *encodedString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(CFStringRef)dm.strAzureEmail,NULL,(CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",kCFStringEncodingUTF8 ));
```

My email address is like `abctest@company.com`. but from the server still I am getting the error

**The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.**

How can I encode it correctly. Please helpme.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *plainString = @"abctest@company.com";

 NSData *plainData = [plainStringdataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSString *base64String = [plainData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]; 

 NSLog(@"%@", base64String);
```